# Dart find diff between string time and now date in seconds

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a string `"HH:mm"` and I want to find the diff between that string to now time in seconds.

For instance, if the time now is `2021-02-24 18:00:00.000000` and my string is `"00:30"` then the result should be `23400` seconds.

How do I do that in dart?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Why is it 23400 and not 63000?

Comment: Thanks for answering... I'm still struggling to parse my string to the upcoming DateTime in order to diff the times.

It is 23,400 because the string indicates an upcoming time. It mean that there are 6.5 hours between the now time and the string time.

Comment: Yeah I understand that 23400 sec is  6.5 hours. I just wanted to understand how you know that the time always indicates a later time. And for that matter, how it is known that it is only that time the next day and not three days from now? If the string was 19:00, how do you know it is one hour from your "now", and not 25 hours?

Comment: My users pick an hour of the upcoming 24 hours. I don't need to validate it, it is just a fact.

Comment: And further questions are if you know it is the same time zone, and should daylight saving be considered?

Comment: Okej. I understand.

Comment: Just to make it clear, my users pick a time (HH:mm) format and I want to show them a timer. So I have a working timer but I cannot diff the time correctly.

Comment: Okey, I'll add basic building blocks as an answer, I hope you'll manage from that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated answer** to make it match your question better.

Okey, given the answers as I understood from the comments, here is a suggestion. You can of course make it less expressive and combine the rows.

```
  final now = DateTime.parse('2021-02-24 18:00:00.000000');
  String time = '00:30';

  final dateFormat = DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd');
  final todayString = dateFormat.format(now);
  String stringToParse = '$todayString $time:00';
  final parsedDateTime = DateTime.parse(stringToParse);
  final timeDifference = parsedDateTime.difference(now);
  int seconds = timeDifference.inSeconds > 0
      ? timeDifference.inSeconds
      : timeDifference.inSeconds + 86400;

  print(seconds.toString());
```

Will print `23400`